# Allowed Core Data size

Tags: iphone

How much data can we store in Core Data? On which parameter does it depends?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some searching around and couldn't find a hard answer for you to link to. However, Core Data is built on top of Sqlite3 so it should have the same limits. Essentially you should be able to keep storing data until you hit the SQLITE_MAX_PAGE_COUNT limit.

Here is a link to the Sqlite3 implementation limits page, which should answer your question: http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html

**EDIT:** As coneybeare mentioned in the comments, Core Data is actually implemented independently of the underlying storage mechanism. That storage limit I mentioned above is specifically for Sqlite, so should only apply if you use an Sqlite3 backed Core Data instance (although of course they may do something under the hood to change that limit or work around it). From my searches, I could not find a specific limit for a Core Data store, so it's possible that the only limit is the device's storage space.

Comment: Core data is not build ontop of sqlite3.  sqlite is one of the many possible datastore that core data can use, including xml.